# Not able to re-flash bios on laptop

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, dell-latitude

I always re-flash my laptop with the latest BIOS if I have any issues/bugs, recently I had a touchpad issue, with touchpad working only in BIOS so I wanted to reflash BIOS. I ran the executable(.exe) from windows 11 and it just restarts my computer nothing else. After this I went to the BIOS setup menu and tried to initiate a update from there only (UEFI BIOS), it said to choose the bios file from the hard disk, I did that, but here also no success. Now I only have one way left that is to press CTRL+ESC while the laptop is off and then plug in the AC adapter but I am afraid to do so as it RESETS the BIOS and is a more of a HARD RESET. Now I want to ask that is it possible that the BIOS chip on mobo has exceeded the number of times of writes I can perform and now its damaged and is a read only thing.

Also I would like to share that this is a 2014 laptop and I have been using it since 2020. I re-flashed the BIOS (A28) approximately 10 times.

Kindly suggest if I can do anything else.
    
    My Laptop Specs -
     Dell Latitude E7440
     Bios - A28
     Windows 11 PRO (installed after a workaround)
Thanks

Comment: ok, so Rule #1: never flash an EEPROM unless you have a real reason to. flashing motherboard firmware is one of the very few things you can do with software that can legit brick your system (meanding you cannot fix it without returning parts). I do not believe that most ROMS have a write limit you could conceivably reach, but at the same time, you really shouldn't be flashing your BIOS/firmware unless there is an update.

Comment: Without knowing what specific chip your motherboard uses to store the firmware it is hard to know what write limit it might have. Some flash memories do indeed have a low write endurance at maybe 10 or 100 writes, but others have up to 100,000 writes. You would hope that most manufacturers would go for a reasonable in-between figure at maybe 1000 writes but you certainly wouldn't expect a user to refresh their firmware every time their system starts acting weird.

Comment: Since my laptop is a dell Latitude business class laptop and was quite expensive I assume it to have a a good bios chip.

Comment: So can I safely proceed to reinstall the bios via the hard reset method